# Good test database on Windows to play around with data retrieval operations in SQL?

Tags: sql, rdbms, test-data

I need a test database to practice joins and other kinds of data retrieval operations in SQL.

What's a good free test database and RDBMS system to use on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every major RDBMS provider has some free edition. Those are full versions limited by database size and maximum memory usage.

Top players:

- [Sql Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/)
- [Oracle Express](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html)
- [IBM DB2 Express-C](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/download.html)

Then, there is number of open source products:

- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)
- [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)
- [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com)
- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (not really a RDBMS, but understands SQL and it can be used for your purposes. Also, very small and compact)

If this is not enough, check this Wikipedia article: [**Comparison of relational database management systems**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems).
There's more than 50 RDBMS's listed and you'll probably find something that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/) for one.

Sample databases (AdventureWorks) can be [downloaded here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/45907).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e719ecf7-9f46-4312-af89-6ad8702e4e6e&displaylang=en). The adventure works database is used as an example for numerous online and offline resources.

After which, download the [SMSS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for practising SQL you could install Access assuming you have an MS Office CD that includes it already.

Otherwise MySQL or SQL Server Express are probably your best bets.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend MySQL over SQL Server Express if your purpose is to practice SQL.  The command line interface is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get online practice with verifying your queries on [SQL Exercises](http://www.sql-ex.ru)